# Oracle trigger exception and rollback maybe

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Suppose I have the following trigger :

```
create or replace trigger trigInsertSaloane before insert on saloane
for each row
declare
  myExcp exception;
  pragma exception_init (myExcp,-20005);
begin
  for i in (select * from saloane) loop
    if(:new.numar_salon=i.numar_salon) and (trim(upper(:new.nume_sectie))=trim(upper(i.nume_sectie))) then
    raise myExcp;
    end if;
  end loop;
  exception when myExcp then dbms_output.put_line('Record exists');
end;
/
```

All I want is to not insert the row if exception is raised, so something like rollback. In my case if exception is raised and caught, the line is also inserted. I don`t want that. Also I want to make that in a pretty way, by showing up a message and not getting any errors.How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. a few points.

1) you need to raise an exception from a trigger for the insert will fail and not be inserted.  so either do not catch your exception or re `RAISE` it again.

2) using dbms_output.put_line() will only display a message if the user/client has it turned on.

3) you do not need to loop over your cursor. adding a where clause is more efficient

4) your trigger will not work.. it will throw 
`ORA-04091: table SALOANE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` if you insert more then 1 row at a time. (try `insert into saloane select * from saloane` )

5) it may just be your example.. it looks like you could more simply use a unique constraint on the given columns to enforce this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more points as mentined in other answer.

1. Since you are handling the EXCEPTION (PRETTY WELL :p ) in the
   Trigger so ideally Trigger event execution is successful so
   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE will happen.
2. What you need here is to RAISE some kind of exception which will
   force the Trigger to fails with the Exception so
   in this you need to have  `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` condition to
   handle this.
3. As mentioned above UNIQUE Key constraint will be your best friend to
   work in this case.